# Simple Python Game while-loop syntax error

Tags: python

So - I'm new to Python and just messing around with some basic games to get my head around the language.. For whatever reason this little code returns "Invalid Syntax on Line 8" which is the "While guessedwrong == 1" line... Can anyone tell me why?

```
from random import randint

UserResponse = int(input("Guess what number between 1 and 100 I'm thinking 
of!"))
RandomNumber = randint(1,100)
guessedwrong = 1

While guessedwrong == 1:
    If UserResponse > RandomNumber:
        print("Nope! Lower!")
        UserResponse = int(input("Try again!"))
    elif UserResponse < RandomNumber:
        print("Njet! Higher!")
        UserResponse = int(input("Try again!"))
    else
        print("Correct! You're awesome!")
        GuessedWrong = 0
```

Comment: make all characters of `if` and `while` lowercase. Python is case-sensetive programming language.

Comment: `if`, `while` should be in lowercase.

Comment: `guessedWrong = 0`

Comment: `guessedwrong`*

Comment: Also, third last line - Add colon after `else`

Comment: missing `:` after `else`

Answer (score 5):

Python is case sensitive:

```
while guessedwrong == 1:
#^
    if UserResponse > RandomNumber
     #^

    # Some other your code
    else:
    #  ^^
        print("Correct! You're awesome!")
        guessedwrong = 0
        # ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you! Thought it was that easy!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out just now on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Full corrected code

```
from random import randint

UserResponse = int(input("Guess what number between 1 and 100 I'm thinking of!"))
RandomNumber = randint(1, 100)
guessedwrong = 1

while guessedwrong == 1:
    if UserResponse > RandomNumber:
        print("Nope! Lower!")
        UserResponse = int(input("Try again!"))
    elif UserResponse < RandomNumber:
        print("Njet! Higher!")
        UserResponse = int(input("Try again!"))
    else:
        print("Correct! You're awesome!")
        guessedwrong = 0
```